# error: request for member, which is of non class type 'unsigned int'

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I'm having a trouble to debug this code in stl implementation. After testing the code the compiler says the following:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'auto dijkstra_shortest_path(const Graph<T>&, size_t, size_t) [with T = unsigned int; size_t = long long unsigned int]':
> required from 'void test_dijkstra() [with T = unsigned int]'
> required from here
> error: request for member 'vertex_ID' in 'current_vertex', which is of non-class type 'unsigned int'
> ```

The "error: request for member 'vertex_ID' in 'current_vertex', which is of non-class type 'unsigned int'" error is always present on the calling statement `current_vertex.vertex_ID`.

The code is here:

```
auto dijkstra_shortest_path(const Graph<T>& G, size_t src, size_t dest){
    std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>> heap;
    std::set<int> visited;
    std::vector<size_t> parent(G.vertices());
    std::vector<T> distance(G.vertices(), std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    std::vector<size_t> shortest_path;
    heap.emplace(src, 0);
    parent[src] = src;

    while (!heap.empty()){
        auto current_vertex = heap.top();
        heap.pop();
        if (current_vertex == dest){
            std::cout << "Destination " << current_vertex.vertex_ID << " reached." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        if (visited.find(current_vertex.vertex_ID) == visited.end()) {
            std::cout << "Settling vertex " << current_vertex.vertex_ID << std::endl;

            for (auto e : G.outgoing_edges(current_vertex.vertex_ID)) {
                auto neighbor_vertex_ID = e.dest;
                auto new_distance_to_dest=current_vertex.distance_from_source + e.weight;
                if (new_distance_to_dest < distance[neighbor_vertex_ID]) {
                    heap.emplace(neighbor_vertex_ID, new_distance_to_dest);
                    parent[e.dest] = current_vertex.vertex_ID;
                    distance[e.dest] = new_distance_to_dest;
                }
            }
            visited.insert(current_vertex.vertex_ID);
        }
    }
    auto current_vertex = dest;
    while (current_vertex != src) {
        shortest_path.push_back(current_vertex);
        current_vertex = parent[current_vertex];
    }
    shortest_path.push_back(src);
    std::reverse(shortest_path.begin(), shortest_path.end());
    return shortest_path;
}
```

Comment: What is `current_vertex.vertex_ID` supposed to do? `current_vertex` is an `unsigned`, it doesn't have any members.

Comment: Please format error messages in a code block with `\`\`\``, and trim off the `->` prefixes which just make it hard to read.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve]. Are you passing `Graph<unsigned int>`? Perhaps you want to use `std::heap<Node<T>...>` for some `Node` class?

Comment: The curren_vertex.vertex_ID  holds the top in the heap value and performs the following instruction

Comment: @juanp_30 No, it does not hold anything, it is just a number. What type is should have?

Comment: @juanp_30 *"The curren_vertex.vertex_ID holds the top in the heap value"* -- Are you sure? The line `auto current_vertex = heap.top();` makes it look like `current_vertex` (without the `.vertex_ID`) holds the top value.

Comment: At the moment, the example code is a function template without the `template <class T>` line. This causes compilation errors other than the one in the question. To make this example **reproduce** the question's error reproducible, `T` needs to be bound to something; a line like `using T = unsigned;` would do the trick and at the same time avoid the (error message) overhead of templates. Once you do that, please compile just the code that is in the question and update the error message so that it matches the code.

Comment: There is also the "**minimal**" part of "[mre]". Take the first line with the error, then remove everything else from `dijkstra_shortest_path()` that is not required to syntactically support that line (ignore functionality); remove everything you can while preserving the first error message. E.g.: `#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using T = unsigned;
void foo(){
    std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>> heap;
    heap.emplace(0);

    auto current_vertex = heap.top();
    std::cout << "Destination " << current_vertex.vertex_ID << " reached." << std::endl;
}`